# Tish'a Vetish'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred ninety-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> מי שיש לו מאתים זוז לא יטול לקט שכחה ופאה ומעשר עני היו לו מאתים חסר דינר אפילו אלף נותנין לו כאחת הרי זה יטול

That is, "One who has 200 *zuz* shall not take *leket*, *shich'cha*, *pea*, and *maasar ani*. If he had 200 minus a *dinar*, even if 1000 give him at once he may take." From [the *mishna*, *Pea* 8:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%94_%D7%97_%D7%97). Note that a *dinar* is a *zuz*.

Answer (score 3):

Related to msh210's answer, the gematria of צדקה is 199, symbolizing the idea that one who has 199 dinar is still entitled to tzedakah.

([Chida, Midbar Kedeimos, citing Yuchasin](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41714&pgnum=141))

Answer (score 2):

Acc to R' Lazar, Orlah is batel in 199 parts of heter.  ([Yerushalmi Gemara 12b M2H2](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1a02.htm))